# Comment out one or multiple lines of code in CSS

Tags: ios, pixate

The subject says it all: how can I comment out a single (and probably multiply lines of code) in a pixate css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like it's still the same as regular CSS commenting:

```
/* Comment 1 line */

/*
Comment
Multiple
Lines
*/
```

That's what they used in the [Pixate Styling Reference](http://cdn.pixate.com/docs/engine/ios/latest/Pixate%20Engine%20for%20iOS%20Styling%20Reference.html#media)